# How can is Redirect another page in codeigniter4?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I am trying to redirect to the login page after registration using **CodeIgniter4**:

```
helper('url');      
return redirect()->to('pages/login_f');
```

But i am getting the following error:

> 404 - File Not Found
>   Controller or its method is not found: {0}::{1}

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to load helper. Redirect in Codeigniter4 is made with just simple:

```
    ...
    return redirect()->to('pages/login_f');
```

Although, You need to have such controller `pages` and method `login_f` available.
If You can open page `http://.../pages/login_f` in Your browser, then redirection should work. Otherwise You must set specific route in `App/Config/Routes.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

// working well with index function

```
return redirect()->to('public/home');
```

// working well with outside index function

```
return $this->response->redirect(site_url('public/login'));
```

But none of the code is working with library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the controller, you don't need helper function. You can do the following :

```
  function function_name(){
...
return $this->response->redirect('https://' . $redirect_url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You may try this:**

```
return $this->response->redirect(site_url('Put_here_Controller_Name/Put_here_function_Name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
return redirect()->to(base_url().'/pages/login_f');
```

this should probably solve your issue.

Comment: Also check if the route is set correctly.